# Error parsing string to JObject due to html encoded content

Tags: c#, json, .net, console-application

I have a string in JSON format and it has to be converted into a JObject for further actions. The issue with the string is that the content has HTML which is in encoded format. Whenever I try to parse the data, it throws JSON formatted exception.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(html_content);
```

A sample value for html_content is given below.

{"SchemaVersion":1,"ItemData":"{\"messageFrom\":\"8:orgid:d9d75bd6-8e57-40de-b16e-6daf4657cd61\",\"content\":\"this is some gif\\n<img width="\\\"141\\\"" height="\\\"141\\\"" alt="\\\"no" problem="" thumbs="" up="" gif="" by="" vevo="" (gif="" image)\\\"="" src="\\\"https://media0.giphy.com/media/JwjBy94VzDd6/giphy.gif?cid=de9bf95ejqraeuwespjzc4fudg6dwlfah5po7puihwretf7s&rid=giphy.gif\\\"" style="\\\"width:141px;" height:141px;="" max-height:250px\\\"="">\\n\\n\\n\\n\",\"conversationId\":\"19:9bf9f646daab40f69d719724b5e5447e@thread.tacv2\",\"topic\":\"Lowkey Channel\",\"creationDate\":\"2020-08-13T20:41:39.920Z\",\"lastModifiedDate\":\"2020-08-13T20:49:53.200Z\",\"documentId\":\"NGU2MWUwMDA1OGFkNDg2NmEzZThjZGEzNjI5YzMzMmF8MTk6OWJmOWY2NDZkYWFiNDBmNjlkNzE5NzI0YjVlNTQ0N2VAdGhyZWFkLnRhY3YyfDM0M4ODA2ODk4NDU4NjEwMDA=\",\"from\":{\"internalId\":\"8:orgid:d9d75bd6-8e5-40de-b16e-6daf4657cd61\",\"tenantId\":\"7fa6db59-881c-4861-9c77-06d7de40e6ed\",\"userAADObjectId\":\"d9d75bd6-8e57-40de-b16e-6daf4657cd61\",\"displayName\":\"Josh Shih\"},\"to\":[{\"internalId\":\"8:orgid:06d129ae-d8c2-447b-abe3-fd016c34ed69\",\"tenantId\":\"7fa6db59-881c-4861-9c77-06d7de40e6ed\",\"userAADObjectId\":\"06d129ae-d8c2-447b-abe3-fd016c34ed69\"}],\"clientMessageId\":3493880689845861000,\"serverMessageId\":1597351299920,\"parentMessageId\":1597351299920,\"messageVersion\":1597351793200,\"properties\":\"{\\\"emotions\\\":[{\\\"key\\\":\\\"like\\\",\\\"users\\\":[{\\\"mri\\\":\\\"8:orgid:ca368f14-c1be-4e05-a3c6-87bce16d4472\\\",\\\"time\\\":1597351793210,\\\"value\\\":\\\"1597351792722\\\"}]}]}\",\"threadId\":\"19:9bf9f646daa40f69d719724b5e5447e@thread.tacv2\",\"threadType\":\"Space\",\"threadSubType\":\"PrivateChannel\",\"groupId\":\"19:9bf9f646daab40f69d719724b5e5447e@thread.tacv2\",\"aadGroupId\":\"4e61e000-58ad-4866-a3e8-cda3629c332a\",\"messageType\":\"RichText\",\"messageSubtype\":\"Html\",\"type\":\"Message\",\"imdisplayname\":\"Josh Shih\",\"skipDlpClassification\":true}","SkypeItemId":"fb0dd5967567f3bb511a859e0bb584be49f9951c0b3d27021a634ac4801078","SkypeItemId@is.Queryable":true,"LastModifiedDateTime":"2020-08-13T20:49:53.2Z","LastModifiedDateTime@is.Queryable":true,"CreatedDateTime":"2020-08-13T20:41:39.92Z","CreatedDateTime@is.Queryable":true,"ThreadId":"19:9bf9f646dab40f69d719724b5e5447e@thread.tacv2","ThreadId@is.Queryable":true,"ThreadType":"Space","ThreadType@is.Queryable":true,"SkypeGroupId":"19:9bf9f646daab40f69d719724b5e5447e@thread.tacv2","SkypeGroupId@is.Queryable":true,"MessageType":"RichText","MessageType@is.Queryable":true,"FromSkypeInternalId":"8:orgid:d9d75bd6-8e57-40de-b16e-6daf4657cd61","FromSkypeInternalId@is.Queryable":true,"TeamName":"Yappy","TeamName@is.Queryable":true,"Topic":"Lowkey Channel","Topic@is.Queryable":true,"ParentMessageId":"1597351299920","ParentMessageId@is.Queryable":true,"HasCardAttachments":false,"HasCardAttachments@is.Queryable":true,"#type.SkypeItemId":"String","#type.LastModifiedDateTime":"DateTime","#type.CreatedDateTime":"DateTime","#type.ThreadId":"String","#type.ThreadType":"String","#type.SkypeGroupId":"String","#type.MessageType":"String","#type.FromSkypeInternalId":"String","#type.TeamName":"String","#type.Topic":"String","#type.ParentMessageId":"String","#type.HasCardAttachments":"Bool"}

I have tried decoding the HTML before the parsing. But that did not help.

Comment: The json is not valid - the embedded Html content has broken the json format. How is `html_content` being created? You'll need to figure out how to add the Html without breaking the json before you can try to parse it. And we'll need to see how you're creating `html_content` before we can help

Comment: @haldo the content parsed from the script tag taken from Microsoft teams advanced export